Docker-Compose interpolation of service name
Is it possible to use the service name as variable in your docker-compose.yml?
version: '3.4'

services:
  foobar:
    image: bla/blubb
    volumes:
      - /path/to/${SERVICENAME}:/data

/path/to/${SERVICENAME} should interpolate to /path/to/foobar then.
The environment variable COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME seems to include the service name. I couldn't find another variable.

None of the standard Compose environment variables include the service name; indeed, they are all constant across the entire Compose file(s), and none of them vary service to service.
It's typical to treat the Compose service name as a fixed string.  There's not a good way to use a variable here, especially not one that will change values between services.
services:
  foo:
    volumes:
      - ./data/foo:/data
      # ^^^^^^^^^^ fixed local path (relative to Compose file) is fine
  bar:
    environment:
      FOO_URL: http://foo/
      #               ^^^ fixed service name in URLs is fine
    volumes:
      - ./data/bar:/opt/bar/data

(You could imagine wanting to use this with YAML anchor syntax.  Different images will frequently have different container storage paths, and it might be hard to reuse a block like this across services.  The container-side storage path and listening port are generally fixed properties of their images, and I wouldn't try to parameterize these at the Compose level.)
